# Adding a "Delete Row" Button to Infopath form on SharePoint Online asking for Admin Approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Been looking for a solution to add a "delete row button" for each row on a repeated table form.
Migrated over to SharePoint Online but since InfoPath is being depreciated by 2026 some of the InfoPath toggles that was in Central Admin (as is Central Admin) is gone from SP Online.

I get this error
[image]
when I tried to publish a form where I used the edit code button (for a button element) and added this code:

```
e.Source.DeleteSelf();
```

It works perfectly sand-boxed but since sand-boxed solutions have also been depreciated I suppose I am getting this error.
Is there a way around this or another solution to make a 'Delete Row" button in a Repeated Table Form? 
Yes I have Farm/Admin rights.
SP Online, InfoPath 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend trying out [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/) solution for creating complex SharePoint forms. It's not free, but it's much cheaper than if you'd implement a form with data table by yourself with HTML and JavaScript. It provides a [Data Table](https://plumsail.com/docs/forms-sp/how-to/save-table-signature.html) control for adding repeatable items and saving them in a separate SharePoint column of the current item; and [List or Library](https://plumsail.com/forms/list-or-library/) control which allows you to configure parent/child relationship between multiple lists and edit all data in a single form.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry but the company frowns on adding third party solutions.